# for Loop 2d array BufferedWriter is not writing to txt

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, writer

I have this code:

```
        try {
        File file = new File("newbook.txt");
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file, true);
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }
        for (int r = 0; r < StuGrades.length; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < StuGrades[0].length; c++) {
                //out.write(StuGrades[r][c]);
                out.write(" " + StuGrades[r][c]);
            }
        }
    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("something's wrong");
    }
```

It runs no error, but it doesn't write anything in the txt.

Comment: Don't forget to close your file

Comment: Charles is right, close it and it will be working fine

Comment: oh my. I didn't know forgot to close it would have such different.

Comment: @MarkYo BufferedWriter, as the name implies, buffers the data in memory before writing it out to file. When you do a close it flushes the buffer onto the file before closing it. You can also call `flush()` to see the edit immediately (but still need to close it to avoid leak).